# Dedupe CloudPages DE records

Tags: marketing-cloud, duplicate-management

I was building a test Cloud Page using the system CloudPages DE to capture user preferences.

It had no problem capturing input information. However, when users re-entered their info and change their preferences, it created another record instead of updating it against the original record.

Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Smart Capture to capture user preferences, according to the Salesforce Documentation you can set the form action to Upsert to Data Extension which will do the following:

1. Create a new record if no record is found with the unique identifier
2. Update a record if the record already exists with the unique
   identifier

Please refer to the [Smart Capture Form Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture_form_actions.htm&type=5) for more action types.

Comment: I've lodged a ticket and spoken with the support agent. Apparently there's no out-of-the-box, non-programmer friendly functionality to change the submit action. The only way to do it is through AmpScript or javascript